# c++ socket question

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, process, file-descriptor

When I get a new file descriptor from accept() and fork a new process directly after that does the new process get the file descriptor? Second in the parent process can I close the descriptor or will this affect the child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes it gets.
2. Yes you can close the descriptor and this wouldn't affect to child (of course if you closing descriptor after fork in main process)

Comment: The child process gets copies of all open file descriptors from the parent.